# How do I use the data from a get request with axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, vite

When I try to use variables from outside of the function i get: Uncaught ReferenceError: fetchArray is not defined. But it works without trouble in a fetch get request

```
getWithAxios() {
        axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/' + this.randomArray)
          .then(function (response) {

          console.log(response.data);

          this.fetchArray = response.data

        })
      }
```

Comment: Create a function and pass `response.data` in to it. See the duplicates for more details on the pattern to use when handling async data